# Camel ActiveMQ replyTo Issues

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

Getting a exception when trying to use replyTo. Requirement is to receive reply from external queue . Not sure why I am getting timeout error, do I have to make any configuration changes or any code changes . Tried different ways, but it’s not working . Any help will be appreciated

I am reading file from folder, split the file and sending results to req queue and expecting a reply on req2

```
    from("file://C:/pkuma1?fileName=request464.txt").routeId(messageType+"sasasas")
    .split()
    .tokenize("\\n")
    .log(INFO,"i am initial")
    .setHeader("JMSReplyTo", simple("req2"))
    .inOut("amq://queue:req?replyTo=req2&preserveMessageQos=true&replyToType=Shared&receiveTimeout=250")
   // .inOut("amq://queue:req")
    .transform(constant("Bye Camel"))
    .log(INFO,"msg id initial = ${in.header.JMSMessageId}")
    .log(INFO,"corr id initial = ${in.header.JMSCorrelationID}")
    .to("stream:out");

    from("amq://queue:req")
    .log(INFO,"i am second route")
    .log(INFO,"msg id second route = ${in.header.JMSMessageId}")
    .log(INFO,"corr id second route = ${in.header.JMSCorrelationID}");
    .setHeader("JMSCorrelationID", simple("${in.header.JMSCorrelationID}"));
    .transform(simple("Hello in second route ${in.body}"))
    .process(exchange -> {
        System.out.println(exchange);
        System.out.println("route2");
    });
    //.end();
    //.to("amq://queue:req2");
    
    from("amq://queue:req2?disableReplyTo=true")
    .log(INFO,"i am third route")
    .log(INFO,"msg id third route = ${in.header.JMSMessageId}")
    .log(INFO,"corr id third route = ${in.header.JMSCorrelationID}")
    .setHeader("JMSCorrelationID", simple("${in.header.JMSCorrelationID}"))
    .transform(simple("Hello ${in.body}"))
    .process(exchange -> {
        System.out.println(exchange);
        System.out.println("route3");
        System.out.println(exchange.getIn().getHeader("JMSCorrelationID"));
        exchange.getIn().setBody("Hello ${in.body}");
        exchange.getIn().setHeader(JmsConstants.JMS_DESTINATION, "");
        exchange.getIn().setHeader("JMSReplyTo","");
        exchange.getIn().setHeader("JmsDestination","");
        exchange.getIn().setHeader("CamelJmsDestination","");
    })
    .to("stream:out")
    .end();
```

Getting following error Timeout occurred after 120000 millis waiting for reply message with correlationID

Comment: I'm not sure your approach makes sense. If you use `.inOut()` with JMS, Camel will expect a response _in the same route_. It seems you've set a reply-to address that will direct the reply to a different route. The reply may be read, but Camel won't be able to correlate it with the original request.  I think the Camel JMS endpoint expects to set up the request-reply machinery itself, and deliver the response into the same route that generated the request.

Comment: I am expecting a synchronous call from main route ( main route waits for a response from req2). From main route I am sendBig a request to req queue and expecting a reply from req2 queue

Comment: As I understand it, you're reading the `req2` queue in a separate route. I would expect the message to be received, but it wouldn't be a "response" in the sense that Camel uses that term.

Comment: Yes, I am reading the req2 queue in a separate route, expecting a message to received in main route

Comment: But why would you expect that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221933/discussion-between-praveen-and-kevin-boone).